# ZIp Codes to City Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a column of zip codes in excel spreadsheet into city names, but I keep getting a weird output in the desired new column. I want to have one column be the zip codes and the second column to be the city name.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
import zipcodes
from uszipcode import SearchEngine
search = SearchEngine()

zipcode_data = pd.read_excel(r"Hospital Evaluations.xlsx", sheet_name="Zip")

df_zip_code = zipcode_data['Zip Code'].drop_duplicates().to_frame()
df_zip_code['City'] = df_zip_code['Zip Code'].map(lambda x: search.by_zipcode(x))
zip_code_map = df_zip_code.set_index('Zip Code')['City']
zipcode_data['Zip Code'] = zipcode_data['Zip Code'].map(zip_code_map)

zip_code_map
```

Output:

```
Zip Code
NaN                                                   None
60615    SimpleZipcode(zipcode='60615', zipcode_type='S...
60187    SimpleZipcode(zipcode='60187', zipcode_type='S...
60573                                                 None
60517    SimpleZipcode(zipcode='60517', zipcode_type='S...
60480    SimpleZipcode(zipcode='60480', zipcode_type='S...
60619    SimpleZipcode(zipcode='60619', zipcode_type='S...
60642    SimpleZipcode(zipcode='60642', zipcode_type='S...
60607    SimpleZipcode(zipcode='60607', zipcode_type='S...
60509                                                 None
`                                                     None
60403    SimpleZipcode(zipcode='60403', zipcode_type='S...
60554    SimpleZipcode(zipcode='60554', zipcode_type='S...
60561    SimpleZipcode(zipcode='60561', zipcode_type='S...
60532    SimpleZipcode(zipcode='60532', zipcode_type='S...
60433    SimpleZipcode(zipcode='60433', zipcode_type='S...
60507    SimpleZipcode(zipcode='60507', zipcode_type='P...
60189    SimpleZipcode(zipcode='60189', zipcode_type='S...
Name: City, dtype: object
```